# How to obtain a directory name inside of a directory not knowing the exact name in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a directory called: example
Inside of directory "example" I have 3 subdirectories:

blah123-words
random123-words
stuff123-words

The problem is "123" integers in the subdirectories will keep changing to new ones like 124, 125, 126, etc...

Is there a way to obtain blah123-words directory inside of example and store it as a string or something?

but only searching for "blah" and have Java automatically grab the whole directory name? and store it as a string or whatever. I would like to eventually output this directory name into a .xml file or a .txt file.

Comment: A little piece of code here would be nice to see!

Comment: Have you looked at the methods of File?  Specifically `list()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the File object's `.list()` which returns all children files of a directory in a String[].

```
File f = new File("path_to_directory");
String[] list = f.list();
String keeper = "";

for(String s: list){
    if(s.contains("blah")){
       keeper = s;
    }
}
```